# Создание полноценного приложения на QT Creator 4.14

Tags: c++, qt

Хотел сделать из программы на QT Creator(язык c++) полноценное приложение, чтобы оно работало не только там, где есть сам QT, но при переключении режима с Отладка на Выпуск и при запуске файла у меня не создаётся exe файл в подпапке release папки build-plotting-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug. Само приложение включает себя файлы QCustomPlot. В чём может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Почитайте тут https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: А в папке `build-plotting-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Release` не смотрели?

Comment: Юрий, такой папки нет

Comment: Похоже, в этом и заключается проблема. Эта папка не создаётся автоматически при сборки с release. Возможно ли решить это как-нибудь без переустановки новой версии qt?